# Can't run org-refile function in Spacemacs

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I am using GNU Emacs 27.1 with Spacemacs 0.300. I am new to Emacs and Org-mode. I want to use the function [org-refile](https://orgmode.org/manual/Refile-and-Copy.html#Refile-and-Copy) with the shortcut C-c C-w. However, this is what I get:

[image]

Why can't I use that function?

Besides, do you recommend using Spacemacs or Vanilla Emacs for someone who is learning?

Thanks in advanced!

EDIT

The issue had something to do with Spacemacs and its key bindings. I ended up switching to Vanilla Emacs. Since I am just starting with Emacs, I feel more in control than with Spacemacs.

Comment: I think you need to be in an `org-mode` buffer before `C-c C-w` does what you want and, from the screenshot, it does not look like you are.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't open a org-mode buffer for taking the screenshot. The issue remains the same!

Comment: Please don't use screenshots: cut and paste text into your question and use [Markdown formatting](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/editing-help). It's not clear from the screenshot what result you got: did you get an error message? If so, that has to be included in the question.

Comment: I included an screenshot because it seems that Spacemacs is waiting for some additional shortcut to complete the command C-c C-w. I am quite new both to Emacs and Spacemacs but I think I am getting a list of possible shortcuts to complete because somehow C-c C-w is not bing to org-refile?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `eyebrowse-mode` than it can work.

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook '(lambda () (eyebrowse-mode -1)))
```